Are there any CubeSat telescopes? What are the requirements?
Are there any CubeSats that perform as telescopes for deep-space photography?
If I have a CubeSat of let's say 6U, designed for Earth Observation (meaning it could be restricted in terms of the camera sensor  e.g. only capturing RGB images), can it also point to space and, under the right external circumstances (that could mean that it's in a position where the sun is not a distraction), capture space images?
Or is the whole concept of a CubeSat too limited for space photography?
What I know is that, CubeSats are typically very small, resulting in limitations regarding the size of the sensors they can carry. This can be challenging, since it is known that larger lenses and sensors generally capture more light, which is essential when it comes to astro-photography.
Also, long exposure is a must when it comes to astro-photography so, a trusted stabilization system is crucial to the cause, since long exposure will also capture any external disturbance.

So, what's so bad about using a telescope on the ground?

@user3528438 nothing in particular! I was curious on what would change in terms of requirements, if a CubeSat made for EO was also used for out of Earth uses.

There is the CUTE satellite for spectroscopic measurements in the ultraviolet https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorado_Ultraviolet_Transit_Experiment but that is plagued with pointing issues, as it can't carry reaction wheels.

tl;dr: Cubesats can observe for months or even years what sounding rockets can observe for minutes! For any wavelength that doesn't make it to high altitude balloon level, cubesats may be the best way to go!


Are there any CubeSat telescopes? What are the requirements?

Have a look at Cubesat with 8 arcsecond pointing accuracy - is that typical, or exceptional? and its answer, which describes a 3U cubesat telescope carrying all the necessary attitude stabilization technology as (in part) a demonstration of what is possible.

Miniature X-Ray Solar Spectrometer (MinXSS) - A Science-Oriented, University 3U CubeSat
MinXSS-1 website (lots of goodies)
Science Missions with CubeSats Sure are Fun! The Story of the MinXSS CubeSats Nice review and photos (also archived)

It may not be cheap or COTS-available (I just don't know) but cubesat telescopes that point at the heavens are indeed a thing.
In this case, the Sun is the target, and the telescope images low energy or "soft" X-rays (just above what we might call vacuum ultraviolet) that can not be accessed from Earth's surface.

Or is the whole concept of a CubeSat too limited for space photography?

No it is not! Think about the hundreds the UV and X-ray telescopes that have been put on sounding rockets for just a few minutes of observing time!

What I know is that, CubeSats are typically very small, resulting in limitations regarding the size of the sensors they can carry. This can be challenging, since it is known that larger lenses and sensors generally capture more light, which is essential when it comes to astro-photography. Also, long exposure is a must when it comes to astro-photography so, a trusted stabilization system is crucial to the cause, since long exposure will also capture any external disturbance.

For wavelength ranges that don't reach Earth's surface (or at least high altitude balloons)

Would it have been cheaper and/or faster to put a James Webb-like Space Telescope on a balloon instead of a rocket?

observing is limited to a handful of space telescopes which are in extremely high demand. You have to propose and wait, get accepted, schedule, and then a year later you may get a few hours or a few tens of hours of observing time that year.
There are plenty of interesting things to observe that don't need major space telescope observatories, and don't need extremely large apertures and/or exposure times. Remember that aperture gives us resolution as well as light. If your topic of interest can be measured without high resolution, then a cubesat might be a good solution for other reasons.
There is still a scientific "market" for lower-cost, faster turnaround time cubesat-based measurements.
For example, you may need an extended observing schedule - 5 minutes a day, every day for a year. That's quite hard to get on a big space telescope. Or you may need to watch a specific single target as continuously as possible, for months or years, waiting for something sudden to happen (like a supernova). Again you can't dedicate a big space telescope for that.

Automated (and hopefully free) systems I can subscribe to sending email or SMS text message when the T Coronae Borealis Nova becomes visible?
Is there a standardized "Astronomical Alert" system?
Astronomy SE Questions tagged with "time-domain-astronomy"

Finally, the pointing problem may not be as bad as one might think. While exposure times of hours or days may be needed for a dim object, most CCD-based readout systems (which are also used to read out arrays sensitive to non-visible light wavelengths) are flushed every few minutes. It's not light photographic emulsion where you need to maintain rock-solid pointing for hours. Just like modern cameras, you can digitizes at higher cadence and do post-alignment in software.
I think that the title of Feynman's famous lecture on the possibility of nanotechnology can also apply to space telescopes: There's plenty of room at the bottom (Here's the written version, archived

In theory, a cubesat could do space photography, but the question is what benefit you'd get from the huge cost of launching it into space.
Looking down is one thing: There's no ground- or air-based system that could produce images similar to even a relatively low quality camera in low orbit. Looking up, not so much. We've had a few centuries to get very good at looking up.
In short, a telescope small enough to fit in a 6U cubesat is going to have a much smaller light collector than a high-quality portable consumer telescope, never mind a small university observatory's telescope. You can avoid some atmospheric distortion, but at that level of magnification, you really aren't going to be dealing with serious distortion problems anyway. In short, if your orbital photography platform is getting serious competition from a Celestron in the back of somebody's car, we have to really wonder why we'd put in the effort of a space launch.
There could be a benefit if you were interested in looking at specific parts of the spectrum that are blocked by our atmosphere, but that's not really astro-photography at that point and you'd want to build an instrument to specifically examine those parts of the spectrum.

Might be more useful to have modest sized non-terrestrial telescopes in a decade when there could be 50,000-70,000 LEO sats between the Kuiper, OneWeb, Starlink, and Thousand Sails constellations

I don't think such objects would be enough to impact the modest viewing you'd get from a cubesat or backyard telescope.

"There's no ground- or air-based system that could produce images similar to even a relatively low quality camera in low orbit" You're going to get far better quality putting the same camera on a drone or Cessna 172. It's an issue of time and cost for a given coverage area.

@fyrepenguin and a cubesat sitting in an even lower orbit wouldn't do anything there except making the clutter even worse.

@jwenting It would, as the cone of a fixed camera FOV is narrower when it is closer to the other satellites. For example with 1° view, a telescope at Earth surface has 9x9 km zone for 500 km orbit Starlink satellites to disturb. Same telescope at 400 km cubesat altitude only has 2x2 km, for 20 times less probability. Having similar orbital speed could also provide longer uninterrupted observation times.

@user71659 Depends on what you're trying to record. That's true if you want a "google maps" style bird's-eye view of cities, but if you were studying cloud development in the south pacific, a Cessna won't do you much good.

surely anything where you're looking in the UV or e.g. the water absorption bands in the IR kinda needs to be above the atmosphere, right?

@Kaia That's what the last paragraph is referring to, but also the question is about photography using standard visible-light image collection. ("meaning it could be restricted in terms of the camera sensor e.g. only capturing RGB images")
